# Set ignored signals to SIG_DFL before execvp()

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix, execvp

I'm writing a library where I fork() and execvp() to start another program. As I've understood, execvX() resets "custom" signal handlers to SIG_DFL but it doesn't set any ignored signals handlers to SIG_DFL.

Keeping in mind it is a library and I can't control what users will do with the signals, is it a good idea to set the signal handlers of ignored signals to SIG_DFL?

If it is, is there some way to set all signal handlers to SIG_DFL at once? Do I have to iterate through all signals numbers instead? And in this case, how can I find the last possible signal number? I've seen there is _NSIG in bits/signum.h. Is this constant part of POSIX or is it Linux-specific?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page,

> The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset to the
>                 default ([signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

The `signal(7)` man page adds:

> During an `execve(2)`, the dispositions of handled signals are
>          reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.

So you need to reset one by one the signals you want to ignore or default before your `execve`

And I see an `NSIG` constant in `/usr/include/signal.h`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize NSIG.

Comment: See also `feature_test_macros(7)` man page, you may want  `-D_GNU_SOURCE`